# Keep first occurrence row by id and first occurrence when value in column changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, unique

In the following example df, what is the best approach to keep:

- The first row when a `Score` appears for each `id`
- Then the first row when a value changes in `Score` for each `id` and drop duplicated rows until it changes

**Example df**

```
      date      id   Score
0   2001-09-06  1       3
1   2001-09-07  1       3
2   2001-09-08  1       4
3   2001-09-09  2       6
4   2001-09-10  2       6
5   2001-09-11  1       4
6   2001-09-12  2       5
7   2001-09-13  2       5
8   2001-09-14  1       3
```

**Desired df**

```
      date      id   Score
0   2001-09-06  1       3
1   2001-09-08  1       4
2   2001-09-09  2       6
3   2001-09-12  2       5
4   2001-09-14  1       3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `diff`:

```
print (df[df.groupby("id")["Score"].diff()!=0])

         date  id  Score
0  2001-09-06   1      3
2  2001-09-08   1      4
3  2001-09-09   2      6
6  2001-09-12   2      5
8  2001-09-14   1      3
```

The first appearance will always result in `NaN` which !=0.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic:

```
# shift Score within id
# shifted score at each group start is `NaN`
shifted_scores = df['Score'].groupby(df['id']).shift()

# change of Score within each id
# since first shifted score in each group is `NaN`
# mask is also True at first line of each group
mask = df['Score'].ne(shifted_scores)

# output
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
         date  id  Score
0  2001-09-06   1      3
2  2001-09-08   1      4
3  2001-09-09   2      6
6  2001-09-12   2      5
8  2001-09-14   1      3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df.groupby(['id', 'score']).first()
```

Comment: does it match OP's expected output?

Comment: This will miss the last row in the sample data as it is a duplicate on both columns.